# PHP Comparing date in table with current date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to compare a stored date to the current date, and send back data accordingly. I'm not fluent in PHP so this is what I have so far

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $event_date_str = $row["date"];
    $todays_date_str = date("m-j-Y");

    $today = strtotime($todays_date_str); 
    $event_date = strtotime($event_date_str);
    if($event_date > $today){
    $event = array();
    $event["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $event["name"] = $row["name"];
    $event["longitude"] = $row["longitude"];
    $event["latitude"] = $row["latitude"];
    $event["pavement"] = $row["pavement"];
    $event["traffic"] = $row["traffic"];
    $event["environment"] = $row["environment"];
    $event["image_b64"] = $row["image_b64"];
    $event["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    $event["date"] = $row["date"];
    $event["time"] = $row["time"];
    $event["type"] = $row["type"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["events"], $event);
    }else{
    //delete it here
    }
```

With that code right there I am getting nothing back. I have 2 items stored in the database, One with the date "2-28-2014" and another with "2-14-2014", so I should be getting one back and not the other but I am getting neither back. I know that there are no leading zeros with the dates saved so I should use j right? Could someone help me figure out why this is not working, sorry if it seems like a simple question.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Comment: It would help you posted the code that is actually relevant to your problem. For starters, your query would be helpful to see. Additionally, what is the data type of your date column?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an efficient way to do things. If you need to pick items based on date, do it in the MySQL query directly. PHP filtering will always be slower than MySQL. Especially since you have to deliver extra data over network when filtering at PHP level.

So do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `record_expires_datetime_gmt` > UTC_TIMESTAMP();
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `record_expires_date_gmt` > DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP());
// use NOW() for local time, UTC_TIMESTAMP() is GMT/UTC
```

Then do what you need to do with the records. Never `SELECT *` and then filter records in PHP.

There's a whole set of [`DATETIME` functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in MySQL to allow you MySQL server side filtering of data.

**PS**: Obviously, for this method to work, your MySQL table has to be properly designed. Date *(date and time)* fields need to be of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` not surrogate strings that are meaningful only within your project.

Comment: What happens is they set a date for the event and then it saves that. What would I have to change to for it to go into type DATE? I get that I'll have to change the structure to include a type DATE.

Comment: @TylerM You need to convert the event date from user input value to `YYYY-MM-DD` *(or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` for datetime)* format for `MySQL`. So when you `INSERT` the data, make sure the date is correct *(in either local or global (GMT) time)*.

Comment: I think I'll just be using DATE since the time won't matter. And would $event_date_arr = explode("-", //WHERE);$event_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $event_date_arr[2], $event_date_arr[0], $event_date_arr[1]); and then INSERT $event_date into the type DATE field in the table?

Comment: @TylerM Are you trying to convert a `DATETIME` to a PHP integer timestamp? You have `strtotime()` for that.

Comment: With the code I just posted I was trying to convert the date that is send from the app to database into a format that matched type DATE so it could be saved in the DATE field.

Comment: @TylerM `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $unix_timestamp)` or `gmstrftime('%Y-%m-%d', $unix_timestamp)`. That's the format. Just get a timestamp there with `strtotime()` or `mktime()`.

Comment: I tried $event_date = strtotime($_POST['date'], '%m-%j-%Y'); where $_POST['date'] is the date from the app coming in as "MM-DD-YYYY" but it doesn't save right. I also have $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE `record_expires_date_gmt` > DATE(UTC_TIMESTAMP())") or die(mysql_error()); if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){//code posted in main question}

Comment: It's **`strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $timestamp)`** FFS! What's with the `strtotime('%m-%j-%Y')`? I'm done here.

Comment: Here -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html. I have a string in $_POST['date'] as "MM-DD-YYYY", in that link it shows STR_TO_DATE(str,format), $_POST['date']->str, '%m-%j-%Y'->format where %j is the code for the day of the month without leading zeros.